# How do I connect to a Windows Remote Desktop with a Terminal Services Gateway in OS X?

Tags: software-recommendation, remote-desktop

The Microsoft-provided RDP client here:

http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client

Does not support connecting via a Terminal Services Gateway. Are there any other options?

Comment: Would a VNC client provide a useable workaround?

Comment: No - I'm a developer on the Microsoft stack, and when I'm working remotely I want fast performance. So far, Windows 7 RDP client, or even the new 2.1 client from MS works the best if I'm on the network, but remotely, that won't work (unless you use VPN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, neither [Microsoft's own client](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client) nor the popular [CoRD](http://cord.sf.net/) alternative currently support it, [and the latter likely won't for a while](http://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/cord/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=133).

I haven't tested it, but the €20 [iTap](http://itap-mobile.com/desktop/rdp) claims to support it.

Comment: iTap works great! Not sure if I'm ready to shell out the bucks, yet. But it's faster than booting up Boot Camp.